# Ansible conditional matching

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to filter a subset of information out of a list of ec2 inventory information.  In this case, a list of subnets that match a certain condition:

```
- name: Get the VPC ID
  ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
  register: subnet_facts

- debug: "var=subnet_facts.subnets"

- debug: "var={{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ subnet_facts.subnets }}"
  when: "'Public Subnet' in item.tags.Name"
  register: public_subnets
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the error:

```
"The conditional check ''Public Subnet' in item.tags.Name' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('Public Subnet' in item.tags.Name): 'item' is undefined"
```

Is this the best way to filter a list of information based on a conditional?

I took a look at Ansible Filters but they did not seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I have written a really small plugin to solve it. Here is a code of that plugin:

```
from jinja2.utils import soft_unicode

'''
USAGE:
 - debug:
     msg: "{{ vpc.subnets | get_public_subnets_ids('Type','Public') }}"
'''

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'get_public_subnets_ids': get_public_subnets_ids,
        }

def get_public_subnets_ids(list, tag_key, tag_value):
    subnets_ids = []
    for item in list:
        for key, value in item['resource_tags'].iteritems():
            if key == tag_key and value == tag_value:
                subnets_ids.append(item['id'])

    return subnets_ids
```

you can find the detail usage of this plugin [here](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/vpc/tasks/main.yml#L29)
Hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the links (which I read).  My only question is configuration.  I created an action plugin based on your example and added  'action_plugins = ~/ansible/playbooks/action_plugins/' to my ansible.cfg file but I am seeing "template error while templating string: no filter named 'get_public_subnets_ids'".  What configuration step did I miss so that the ansible script recognizes the plugin/function?

Comment: Figured it out, I was not paying attention.  It was defined as a FilterModule, not an ActionModule.  It needs to go in the filter_plugins directory, not the action_plugins directory